# Android back button pressed

Tags: android, listview

I have a strange problem in my android application. It is an application with 5 activities and there is a problem with some ListViews. When you get to an activity that implements a ListView and you scroll the list down and while the list is scrolling you press the back button the application crashes. Has it something to do with the fact that I implemented the onResume() function, have I missed something?

```
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 33, size is 0
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at ro.service.project.ListAdapter2.getView(ListAdapter2.java:42)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1428)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:641)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:3452)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:2950)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-08 08:27:11.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19157):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
, and the onResume() function:
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        texta.clear();
    }
```

Comment: You should post the stacktrace with the exception from the logcat.

Comment: Also, if you suspect it's to do with your `onResume` implementation, post the code for that too.

Comment: What's in line 42 of your ListAdapter2.java? (I suppose that's your file?). Looks like you're accessing an index from an ArrayList that's actually empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The listview was based on an arraylist witch on the back button pressed was destroyed. So while it was scrolling it was being populated with an unexisting variable.